# Loading WMTS Layer

Tags: qgis, wmts, invalid-layer

I'm trying to access imagery from a WMTS server, but after connecting I get the following error:

> Invalid Layer: WMS provider Cannot calculate extent Raster layer
> Provider is not valid (provider: wms, URI:
> crs=EPSG:3857&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=3inch_Orthos&styles=default&tileMatrixSet=GoogleMapsCompatible&url=https://services.sanborn.com/geo_caches/312021386_Solano_County_Oblique/wmts.xml

I was told that this server requires no authentication.  The only instructions I have for using the server pertain to *Autodesk Civil 3D*, which I don't have, so I'm trying to access the imagery via QGIS.  I'm not GIS-fluent, so I'm kind of stumbling around in the dark, but thought I'd post the problem and see if anyone here sees a clueless newbie problem that's easy to remedy.

P.S.  A colleague says he was able to use the imagery from this server using both *Autodesk Civil 3D* and *ESRI ArcMap*, but was not able to get it to work with QGIS.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Confirmed, Civil 3D 2022 can access it but QGIS 3.18.2 can't. I dunno why.

Comment: I get the same error with QGIS 3.22 on ubuntu.  

Invalid Layer: WMS provider Cannot calculate extent Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: wms, URI: crs=EPSG:3857&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=3inch_Orthos&styles=default&tileMatrixSet=GoogleMapsCompatible&url=https://services.sanborn.com/geo_caches/312021386_Solano_County_Oblique/wmts.xml

The issue reports I found with this error didn't seem to be relevant for the version I was running.  https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/19037 and https://issues.qgis.org/issues/10634

Comment: This isn't a legitimate answer because it doesn't address the problem and error but it is a work around that can allow it to work another way.  The related questions to the right gave me the XYZ tile idea (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178404/wmts-not-loading-in-qgis?rq=1).  

Reading the xml file and adding an XYZ tile source in QGIS of https://services.sanborn.com/geo_caches/312021386_Solano_County_Oblique/3inch_Orthos/{Z}/{X}/{Y}.png seems to work.  It doesn't look like 3 inch imagery through this method of access.